# What does this UML symbol mean?

Tags: java, uml

I was given this UML diagram for java and there was a symbol that I didn't recognize. Could anyone tell me what this means?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a rendering error? Looks like a "5" and a "J" overlayed. After zooming it, it could be a "1" :)

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with UML. I haven't seen any UML notation of that kind before.

Comment: @PsiX It looks like an "I" to me. Serif.

Comment: looks like printing issue to me

Comment: @joe I agree with the others. It appears to be an [over-strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overstrike) (or typographic error) to me. Also, congratulations on passing your eye exam.

Comment: Agreed it may be typo mistake .

Answer (score 0):

Easy question - simply nothing. :)
Probably a rendering error, maybe originating in a multiplicity of an association.

Answer (score 0):

Simply stateted, that is not a UML symbol.